# when to expect @angular/common@"^16.0.0" version support?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

$ ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps --force

```
i Using package manager: npm
‼ Unable to find compatible package. Using 'latest' tag.
‼ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@14.1.1 will be installed and executed.                                                                                                                                              
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@14.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"14.1.1" from the root project
```

try --legacy-peer-deps and --force keys

Comment: No one here can answer this question unless they are a maintainer of the library. There is [a ticket for this on their github](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4498), please follow the progress there

Answer (score 0):

As on 2023-May-22, Ng-Bootstrap doesn't release the supported version for angular 16.x, So we have to wait till we get the updated version.

If you want to use Bootstrap then use the angular lower version 15.x and try to install ng-bootstrap

To install angular package with lower version, use the following CLI

> `npx @angular/cli@15 new YourProjectName`